# c# program unresponsive, how do I find out WHERE it is

Tags: c#

I am a very experienced C/C++ developer, tasked with taking over a c# program. The program in question runs for a bit, then becomes unresponsive. How do I go about finding out WHERE it is locked up at ?

Comment: Use the debugger.

Comment: Use `Console.WriteLine` to output status messages throughout the program.

Answer (score 3):

If you can run it under a debugger, just break it, then look at the stack traces for all threads - especially the main thread. That should tell you where it's hanging.

Answer (score 1):

Run the program while debugging then when it starts to hang up click pause on your IDE and see what is taking so long. Depending on the type UI of app you might want to add some threading to your application

Answer (score 0):

If it is a running program, you can *ATTACH* a debugger to it, and use that to break into its execution to find out where the program is currently by looking at the callstack.

If you can launch the program yourself, then run the program under the debugger. You can break into its execution whenever you want, check out its state (particularly by looking at the callstack), and resume execution.

If you don't have access to the debugger where the program is running, use Task Manager to create a dump of the program, and then examine the dump in WinDbg.exe by loading the dump. You can get WinDbg.exe to give you the callstack of where the program currently is by using `!analyze -v`.